# Mongo DB C# How to update a lot of fields and ignore some fields

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a use case to not update certain values while updating a document for which I tried UpdateOneAsync. The problem with UpdateOneAsync is that the properties I do need to set are ~100 and need to just ignore 2 properties but the syntax of update forces to define each property that needs to be updated

```
var filter = Builders<Employee>.Filter
                .Where(m => m.EmployeeId == request.EmployeeId);

var data = Builders<Employee>.Update
                .Set(m => m.FirstName, request.FirstName)
                .Set(m => m.LastName, request.LastName)
                .Set(m => m.Salary, request.Salary)
                .Set(m => m.LastUpdateDateTime, DateTime.UtcNow)
                .SetOnInsert(m => m.CreatedDateTime, DateTime.UtcNow)
                .SetOnInsert(m => m.CreatedBy, request.CreatedBy);

await _collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, data, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```

I just want to ignore created by and created date time as those will be only set on insert and have all properties from request object updated in the document. Is there an easier way to achieve this. I tried something like this but threw a serialization exception

```
var data = Builders<Employee>.Update
                .Set(m => m, request) <-- This is what I am trying to achieve
                .SetOnInsert(m => m.CreatedDateTime, DateTime.UtcNow)
                .SetOnInsert(m => m.CreatedBy, request.CreatedBy);
```

Mongo Driver currently using - 2.12.*

Answer (score 0):

1. `$Find` the data you want to update
2. Make your request type the same as `Employee`
3. Fill the 2 properties you ignore with the data you just `$Find`
4. `$Set` the whole data.

Comment: But isn't that reading and writing back the same data. I feel it is not performance efficient